# Vertical space before sections using titlesec package

Tags: spacing, titlesec

I am writing my thesis and each section must begin at a new page. I need to have 6 spacing before the sections and 4 spacing after the sections.

My font size is 12 in article format and I am using \doublespacing throughout my thesis via setspace package.

I am doing the following:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}
{0pt}{3\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
```

However latex does not leave 6 spacing before section titles beginning in new page. Sections titles are aligned with the top margin there is no additional vertical spaces before section titles.

Can you help me to solve my problem?

I am adding my codes below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,setspace,array,hyperref,amsthm, titlesec}

\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}

\renewcommand\footnotelayout{\footnotesize}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\usepackage[english,turkish]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.5cm}

\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}

\widowpenalty10000

\clubpenalty10000

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\titlespacing{\section}
{0pt}{3\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=3.5cm,
    top=2.5cm,
    right=2.5cm,
    bottom=2.5cm
}

\begin{document}

\doublespacing

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\lipsum

\newpage

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is your unit here? You ask for "6 spacing", but do `3\baselineskip`. And just to clarify: The basic question is only how to insert the spacing regardless of being at the top of a new page, isn't it?

Comment: I would try to forget ``\titleformat`` and use ``etoobox`` like this :
``\pretocmd{\section}{\clearpage\vspace*{6\baselineskip}}{}{}``
and ``\apptocmd{\section}{\vspace*{3\baselineskip}}{}{}``

Comment: @TeXnician I am using doublespacing throughout the document and write 3\baseline spacing to get 6 spacing. Yes I am asking how to insert the spacing regardless of being at the top of a new page.